# Made script in for selenium webdriver in Eclipce

Tags: java

I'm new to java as well as selenium web driver. I have made a simple script for login and click on 1 button but when i have tried to run it then it couldn't run cause of " NetworkUtils[java Application]? How to solve it?

Comment: Can you provide more details like what kind of server you are using..

Comment: Hi, Currently i'm using internal local server which is connected through cyberoam..!